# How to convert a TStringDynArray to a TStringList

Tags: vcl, tstringlist, c++builder-xe5, tstringdynarray

I'm using `TDirectory::GetFiles()` to get a list of files (obviously).
The result is stored in a `TStringDynArray` and I want to transfer it to a `TStringList` for the sole purpose to use the `IndexOf()` member to see if a string is present in the list or not.

Any solution that will let me know if a certain string is present in the list of files returned from TDirectory::GetFiles() will do fine. Although, it would be interesting to know how to convert the TStringDynArray.

```
TStringDynArray DynFiles = TDirectory::GetFiles("Foo path");
System::Classes::TStringList *Files = new System::Classes::TStringList;

Files->Assing(DynFiles) // I know this is wrong, but it illustrates what I want to do.
if(Files->IndexOf("Bar") { // <---- This is my goal, to find "Bar" in the list of files.

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TStringList` and `TStringDynArray` do not know anything about each other, so you will have to copy the strings manually:

```
TStringDynArray DynFiles = TDirectory::GetFiles("Foo path");
System::Classes::TStringList *Files = new System::Classes::TStringList;

for (int I = DynFiles.Low; I <= DynFiles.High; ++I)
    Files->Add(DynFiles[I]);

if (Files->IndexOf("Bar")
{
    //...
}

delete Files;
```

Since you have to manually loop through the array anyway, you can get rid of the `TStringList`:

```
TStringDynArray DynFiles = TDirectory::GetFiles("Foo path");

for (int I = DynFiles.Low; I <= DynFiles.High; ++I)
{
    if (DynFiles[I] == "Bar")
    {
        //...
        break;
    }
}
```

But, if you are only interested in checking for the existence of a specific file, look at `TFile::Exists()` instead, or even `Sysutils::FileExists()`.

```
if (TFile::Exists("Foo path\\Bar"))
{
    //...
}
```

```
if (FileExists("Foo path\\Bar"))
{
    //...
}
```

<sub>* personally, I hate that the `IOUtils` unit uses dynamic arrays for lists. They are slow, inefficient, and do not integrate well with the rest of the RTL. But that is just my opinion.</sub>

Comment: You are a rock as usual Remy. Yes I thought it was so strange that there where two incompatible classes that I was sure I must have missed something. But maybe there are a grater plan where all this will lead (or not...). I already implemented the linear search approach. Since I have a whole bunch of files to look for I think it will be faster to use lists instead of disk access. Thank you Remy.

Answer (score 1):

`TStrings` knows `TStringDynArray` good enough to provide a member `AddStrings`:

```
Files->AddStrings(TDirectory::GetFiles("Foo path"));
```

will do the job.

Comment: Thank you. The question is 7 years old and maybe your suggestion was supported after that? I will keep this one in mind the next time I need a conversion.